# Is there any difference in packet length of BLE between iOS device?

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying implement an APP with BLE function.

Tried to get data back from UpdatedCharacterteristicValue().

But I found out that when I am expecting to receive about 200 bytes long data.

On my iPhone 12 Pro(iOS 15). It works fine.

On my iPhone 8(iOS 12). It's not working.

If I am expecting to receive about 60 bytes long data.

Both device works fine.

What would be the difference between these two device that cause this result?

Answer (score 1):

Check the negotiated ATT MTU after the connection is established and use it to determine the maximum characteristic size.
The maximum characteristic size you can use on the link is ATT MTU - 3, as 1 byte is used for op-code, and 2 bytes as attribute handle.